# PHP-GD2 is activated, but doesn't create pictures

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

I have on my PC Ubuntu 14.04, Apache2 as webserver and PHP 5.5.9 as intepreter.
I installed with APT the package php5-gd, restarted the server and checked if GD is active with:

```
php -i | grep -i --color gd
```

The output was:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
gd
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => 2.1.1-dev
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0
GDM_LANG => de_DE
GDMSESSION => ubuntu
_SERVER["GDM_LANG"] => de_DE
_SERVER["GDMSESSION"] => ubuntu
```

I wanted to test the libary with this code snippet:

```
<?php
$bild = imagecreatetruecolor(200,250);
$weiss = imagecolorallocate($bild, 255, 255, 255);
$mittelblau = imagecolorallocate($bild, 203, 215, 230);

imagefill($bild, 0, 0, $mittelblau);
imagejpeg($bild, "test.jpg");
?>
```

PHP didn't created a picture. I tried to output the image directly (Yes, I used a header), but Firefox said, that the image is broken.

I hope smb. can help me

Best regards

Noel

EDIT: phpinfo() says, that everything is activated that's related to GD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the mystery. The problem was the file permissions.